# Environmental variable and && parameter

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to build a Batch script to show files that are greater than 1 MB contained in a folder, just for practicing. Everything goes fine except that the script deals with "c" environmental variable as if it doesn't exist. I replaced the if statement with `echo %c%`, the result is echo is off meaning that "c" doesn't exist.

How can I overcome this and if there is another way to accomplish this that would be great also. Thanks for your time by the way.

```
@echo off
set /p a=Enter the extension
cd %~dp0
for /r %%T in (*.%a%) do set /a "c=%%~zT/(1024*1024)" && if %c% geq 1 echo %%~fT is greater than 1 MB
```

Comment: Research Delayed Expansion

Comment: SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

Comment: ok! delayed expansion is how to do it

Answer (score 0):

As the guys said delayedexpansion is how I solved the problem. It will be something like that.
!c! is used to access the new value of c set by the set statement

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /p a=Enter the extension
cd %~dp0
for /r %%T in (*.%a%) do set /a "c=%%~zT/(1024*1024)" && if !c! geq 1 echo %%~fT is greater than 1 MBs
```

Comment: why not simply `if %%~zi geq 1048576 ...`?

Comment: Shouldn't that read `MiB` instead of `MB`? See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte)